# facebook webservices for android

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to use the facebook in my application. I had founded some webservices for dotNet . Like that is there any facebook webservices are available for android . can any one help me please.

ThanQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook have just released their [Official Facebook SDK for Android](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/).  I would recommend that you use that instead of calling the web services directly from your own code.